# How to insert transparent PNG in PDF?

Tags: image, pdf, adobe, imagemagick, png

I am able to insert JPG image into a PDF document with `DCTDecode` filter. I think the all parameters should be the same for `PNG` image too, except the filter which should be `FlateDecode`. However, when I try to insert `PNG` with the same parameters, the PNG image is not visible in he PDF document.

**UPDATE:** I came to conclusion that the PDF file should include

```
1 0 obj <<
/Type /XObject
/Subtype /Image
/Width 512
/Height 512
/BitsPerComponent 8
/ColorSpace /DeviceRGB
/SMask 9 0 R
/Length 134753    
/Filter /FlateDecode
>>
stream
PNG_RAW DATA
endstream
endobj
9 0 obj <<
/Type /XObject
/Subtype /Image
/Width 512
/Height 512
/BitsPerComponent 8
/ColorSpace /DeviceGray
/Length 12087     
/Filter /FlateDecode
>>
stream
ALPHA_PIXELS
endstream
endobj
```

BUT how can I separate the `PNG` raw data and the `alpha pixels` via `ImageMagick`? In other words, what `ImageMagick` command can produce `PDF_RAW_DATA` and `ALPHA_PIXELS` for insertion into the pdf file.

Answer (score 7):

@Bobrovsky

Here is an example: http://pd4ml.com/i/pd4ml18130.pdf

To be more accurate: you cannot embed a PNG absolutely with no manipulations with it. You would need to split a PNG to sections: IDAT (image data) goes to PDF as byte stream unchanged, PLTE (palette) - to colorspace definition, iCCP optionally goes to color profile object.

An object dictionary may look like that:

```
<<
/Filter /FlateDecode
/Type /XObject
/Subtype /Image
/BitsPerComponent 8
/Length 1277
/Height 250
/Width 250
/DecodeParms <<
    /BitsPerComponent 8
    /Predictor 15
    /Columns 250
    /Colors 1
>>
/ColorSpace [/Indexed /DeviceRGB 1 <1989d1ffffff>]
>>
stream
... IDAT bytes ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. I wasn't aware of such a way to embed PNGs.

Comment: @zfr Actually, it's possible to embed a PNG24 image (16 million colors) in a PDF without re-encoding the image, following exactly the same recipe you're giving for a PNG8 image (256 colors). For example (and as a reference), the program [img2pdf](https://gitlab.mister-muffin.de/josch/img2pdf) does just that for non-transparent and non-interlaced images.

Answer (score 4):

Most probably you didn't decode PNG images.

PNGs are not directly supported in PDF. I mean they are not supported in way JPEGs are supported.

You have to produce raw uncompressed raster bytes from PNGs before embedding them into PDF. You may encode the raster bytes with Flate or LZW encoder if you wish.

Comment: Thanks for pointing the issue. I edited my question to find a practical solution.

Comment: With some limitations PNG is supported by PDF directly. PNG should be PNG8 (color type 3), have max 256 colors, have no transparency mask (alpha channel), not be interlaced.

Comment: @zfr do you have an example of a PDF with such PNG embedded?